# understanding the chained data() function in Unslider.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, unslider

was just poking a plugin online called Unslider.js , a simple lightweight carousal plugin i am having a great difficulty understanding the following ine of code in the plugin :

```
me.data(key, instance).data('key', key);
```

now let me explain the context of this line , in the plugin the above line is preceded by the following lines of code :

```
$.fn.unslider = function(o) {
        var len = this.length;

        //  Enable multiple-slider support
        return this.each(function(index) {
            //  Cache a copy of $(this), so it

            var me = $(this),

                // if len less than 1 , the below line returns "Unslider"
                // Else it returns Unslider-1 , Unslider-2 and so on .. 
                key = 'unslider' + (len > 1 ? '-' + ++index : '');      

                instance = (new Unslider).init(me, o);
```

I ran a few tests and found out about the below line ,

```
key = 'unslider' + (len > 1 ? '-' + ++index : '');
```

that, key returns 'slider', if len "is less then" 1 and if more than 1, then the results would look something like 'slider-1', 'slider-2' , 'slider-3' and so on .

The next line that is :

```
instance = (new Unslider).init(me, o);
```

is createing a new instance of Unslider and storing it in instance and after that .

init(me,o) function is executed where ,

me = $(this) and o is nothing but an object literal passed by the user to the plugin .

now i gave all the above explanation , so that everything is not out of context .

now i did go to the Jquery official docs and checked the usage of data().

i saw examples such as :

```
  $( "body" ).data( "foo", 52 );
    $( "body" ).data( "bar", { myType: "test", count: 40 } );
    $( "body" ).data( { baz: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } );
    $( "body" ).data( "foo" ); // 52
    $( "body" ).data(); // { foo: 52, bar: { myType: "test", count: 40 }, baz: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

These examples are quite cute to be honest, but somehow they don't help me understand what i want to .

So coming back to my question ,

```
me.data(key, instance).data('key', key);
```

What does the above line really **Doing** ?

**EDIT ::**

and if i take off that line everything seems to be working just fine , the plugin still works fine and the carousal still slides .

thank you.

Alexander.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When jQuery's `data` is used with two arguements, a key and a value, it stores the value under the given key in an internal object that jQuery keeps track of.

When doing this, jQuery returns the collection, so it can be chained again

```
var me  = $('#element'); // a DOM element

var me2 = me.data('key1', 'value'); // returns same DOM element

me2.data('key2', 'value');
```

is the same as

```
var me  = $('#element'); // a DOM element

me.data('key1', 'value').data('key2', 'value');
```

because the collection is returned, and can be chained.

As for the data stored in `data`, that's something used internally by the plugin, and could be anything, even an object, as long as there's a key to get the data back again, remember this isn't data attributes in HTML, it's an internal store that accepts any data type, even an instance of a function.

As for the key, it just increments to be unique

```
key = 'unslider' + (len > 1 ? '-' + ++index : ''); // the string "unslider-1" etc
```

Then the first call to `data` stores the current instance of the slider

```
me.data(key, instance).data('key', key);
```

while the second one stores the key, as it's easier to just do

```
me.data('key');
```

to get the key back, if you don't know what the last number in the key is, so it's actually a little clever as it lets you do

```
var key = me.data('key');
var instance = me.data(key);
```

and get the correct intance back regardless of the index, increments etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i'll go through it and accept if appropriate . :)